# Where to include css file (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use social buttons as in this site: http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/

It's going to be used in a Ruby on Rails project. I've already got Bootstrap working in the project, but I can't figure out how to add bootstrap-social.

Sorry for the noobish question, but I can't seem to get this right :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use a gem: https://github.com/gavinkflam/bootstrap-social-rails
2. You can download separate files: `bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css` (or scss) and `bootstrap-social/assets/js/docs.js` from a repo in your link http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/ and put them into your `vendor/assets/stylesheets` and `vendor/assets/javascripts` respectively.

Comment: Well, it seems to install, but when I try the example from the website, I don't see a button.

Comment: Nevermind. I never changed my application.css file. (and I needed to install FontAwesome gem).

Answer (score 1):

I would download the Bootstrap-social project and copy the `bootstrap-social` to the project you are currently working on. After that you could say `@import "$file";` in the `application.css` file.